# how to declare sql parametrs in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net

hi i need to get the customer name from the user as in combo box when the user selets the user i want that selected customer name should be searched in the sql table (here table name is "**obbalance** ")and all the entries in the table having the name as the selected customer naem it should be shown in the data grid view

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@p1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString)

cmd = New SqlCommand("select obbalance from balance where custname=@p1", con)

dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
Form2.Show()
```

after thios also it shows a error plz can u help me out if the code is wrong den help me to 
do correct it i am new to vb.net plz ..........
it shows error in declaration so can u send me any other code or if this code den plz send the correct code plz

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@p1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString)

cmd = New SqlCommand("select obbalance from balance where custname=@p1", con)

dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
```

Instead of doing this you can do this also

```
cmd=New SqlCommand("select columnname from tablename where custname='"& ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString &"'",con)
 dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
```

Why do you want parameterized query

Comment: You should never use direct injection of a string input into an SQL statement as this provides an attack vector for hackers.  Using Sanitized parameters is a safer approach

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the parameter **after** creating the new command:

```
cmd = New SqlCommand("select obbalance from balance where custname=@p1", con)

cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@p1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString)

dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
Form2.Show()
```

Additionally, you are creating a *boolean* value as the parameter to the `Add` method:

```
New SqlParameter("@p1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString
```

Do this instead:

```
Dim param as SqlParameter = New SqlParameter("@p1", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
param.Value = ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString)
cmd.Parameters.Add(param)
```

Comment: The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects, not Boolean objects.